# Link in email CakePHP

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I would like to add application link in body email sent with CakePHP framework,
Unfortunately all links are generated with localhost, so I set "App.fullBaseUrl" parameter in config file. 
But I found that it's not properly to hard coded the domain name in config file.

Are there any other solutions with cakePHP to add link in email with domain name without hard coded the domain?

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

Read *the whole page* and not just the first few paragraphs. You already linked the right page [in your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908932/link-in-email-cakephp/27909827#comment-44217983).

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#routing-in-shells-cli

> In command-line interface (CLI), specifically your shells and tasks,
>   env('HTTP_HOST') and other webbrowser specific environment variables
>   are not set.
>
> If you generate reports or send emails that make use of Router::url()
>   those will contain the default host `http://localhost/` and thus
>   resulting in invalid URLs. In this case you need to specify the domain
>   manually. You can do that using the Configure value App.fullBaseURL
>   from your bootstrap or config, for example.
>
> For sending emails, you should provide CakeEmail class with the host
>   you want to send the email with:
>
> `$Email = new CakeEmail(); $Email->domain(‘www.example.org’);` This
>   asserts that the generated message IDs are valid and fit to the domain
>   the emails are sent from.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `Router::url('/', true);`

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for your response, I set true the $fule parameter but it doesn't work, as describe in cakephp docuemntation: "If you generate reports or send emails that make use of Router::url() those will contain the default host http://localhost/ and thus resulting in invalid URLs. In this case you need to specify the domain manually": please read this "http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#routing-in-shells-cli"

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write -

```
echo $this->Html->link('Click Here', array('controller' => 'your-controller', 'action' => 'your-action'), array('fullBase' => true));
```

on your email template page.